# Firefox svg animation freezes on specific PC

Tags: css, firefox, svg, css-animations

I've got this firefox specific [code](http://jsfiddle.net/p3jvpwt4/).

```
    //problem is here
    #mask0 path {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 0;

        transition: all 5s;
    }

    input:checked + svg #mask0 path {
        stroke-width: 1;
    }
```

It works pretty well on different devices, platforms and versions of firefox browser, but on target device (information terminal) it may freeze for long time (few minutes).
Device: intel xeon, 4GB ram, archlinux 64bit, firefox 41.
Problem is not in lack of computer power, because at the moment of freezing cpu useage less than 4% and ram useage less than 10%. Video drivers also checked and working. Other css animations working as required.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'm not sure you're going to get an answer though, just a bunch of comments saying "it works here".

Comment: @MrLister , at least I hope to get some comments saying "it not works here". It can help.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to development version (44) of firefox solved the problem